# Why can't I see Ideas in Community?

Tags: community, lightning-community, ideas

I have made Ideas and Idea themes tabs visible along with CRE for both for System Admin but when logging in to Community, I don't see it. I see the tabs in SFDC proper but not in Community. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: What template have you used? Also I think your question is "Why can I **not** see Ideas in Community?"

Comment: First used the Customer Service template and then tried the Customer Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as of today Ideas is not available for any other templates except for *Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce*. I did try spinning off a new Community with the templates (Customer Service & Customer Account Portal) you mentioned and couldn't see any Idea related component in either [Customer Service](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_napili_views.htm&type=5) or [Customer Account Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_customer_account_portal_pages.htm&type=5) templates.

Upon further search, I could only see [**this idea**](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DtvIAAS) which suggests that Idea components are not available for Napilli template, but seems it's also applicable for all Lightning based templates. I did though find an [appexchange product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000E9l50UAB) which could possibly be used here (*I am by no means affiliated to this product*).

Comment: Thanks so much, I grabbed the AppExchange app and it did the trick! It would be nice if the SFDC documentation for Ideas clearly stated that. The company doesn't want to use the SFDC Tabs + VF template--don't like the looks.

Comment: Glad that this information helped you. Yeah true, there's no mention explicitly about it not working unless you start searching and end up on that idea. I was actually amazed to find it out that Ideas don't work actually in Lightning Community.